# Exception when clicking navigation button during render response phase

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, myfaces

I have a JSF application using MyFaces 2.2.8 and PrimeFaces 5.2 running inside a Tomcat 8.0.23.

All pages are built using Facelets with a top menu and a content area below. On some pages the content area takes a bit longer to render (multiple PrimeFaces DataTables inside a PrimeFaces accordion; accordion tabs are rendered using c:forEach). When I click the menu in the small timeframe when the header is already rendered but the content area is not, I get a NullPointerException.

The menuitem tag looks like this:

```
<p:menuitem value="Text" action="#{bean.doSomething()}" ajax="false"/>
```

*bean.doSomething()* returns a String with the navigation target.

The NullPointerException occurs in `org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.FaceletStateValueExpression.getWrapped()` line 73 because facesContext.getViewRoot() returns null. The value it is trying to resolve is a ui:param that is set inside the c:forEach.

Here is the full StackTrace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.omnifaces.filter.FacesExceptionFilter.doFilter(FacesExceptionFilter.java:69)
at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:198)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:176)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at my.application.web.filter.filter.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:85)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at my.application.web.filter.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.FaceletStateValueExpression.getWrapped(FaceletStateValueExpression.java:73)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.FaceletStateValueExpression.getValue(FaceletStateValueExpression.java:107)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:74)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:137)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstDeferredExpression.getValue(AstDeferredExpression.java:43)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstCompositeExpression.getValue(AstCompositeExpression.java:49)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagValueExpression.getValue(ContextAwareTagValueExpression.java:96)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:74)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagValueExpression.getValue(ContextAwareTagValueExpression.java:96)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getObject(TagAttributeImpl.java:431)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getValue(TagAttributeImpl.java:389)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.java:305)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:50)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:161)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:59)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:48)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:521)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:575)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:553)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:240)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.ui.IncludeHandler.apply(IncludeHandler.java:228)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:55)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.java:373)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:50)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ForEachHandler.applyFirstTime(ForEachHandler.java:385)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ForEachHandler.apply(ForEachHandler.java:228)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:55)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.java:373)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:50)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:46)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:161)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:59)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:48)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:521)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:575)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:553)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:240)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.ui.IncludeHandler.apply(IncludeHandler.java:228)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:46)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:55)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.java:373)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:50)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:86)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:178)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.TemplateContextImpl$TemplateManagerImpl.apply(TemplateContextImpl.java:193)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.TemplateContextImpl.includeDefinition(TemplateContextImpl.java:136)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:476)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:94)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:46)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:55)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.java:373)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:50)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:46)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:59)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:46)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:46)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:48)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:521)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:575)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:553)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:240)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:151)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:59)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:48)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:189)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.buildView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:477)
at org.omnifaces.viewhandler.RestorableViewHandler.restoreView(RestorableViewHandler.java:80)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:82)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:170)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:196)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:143)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.omnifaces.filter.FacesExceptionFilter.doFilter(FacesExceptionFilter.java:63)
... 32 more
```

I tried to reproduce the error with a small example (with and without PrimeFaces), but I am not able to reproduce the NullPointerException. Instead I get a ViewExpiredException when I trigger an action during rendering. (Maybe the NullPointerException is only a sideeffect/aftereffect?)

Here is the content of the sample page (page1.xhtml):

```
<div id="header">
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton action="page2" value="To page 2" />
    </h:form>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <c:forEach var="item" items="#{testBean.list}">
        Click the button!
        <h:dataTable />
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

TestBean.getList() returns a List with 100000 Strings. The button must be clicked after "Click the button!" appears and before rendering/page loading is completed. I get the same error (ViewExpiredException) if I replace c:forEach with ui:repeat.

I also tried to remove the ui:param causing the NullPointerException in my application, but then I get an error that my resource bundle could not be loaded. This supports my theory that the NullPointerException (or the ui:param) is not the real cause of the error, but only a sideeffect/symptom.

I use the default settings for Apache MyFaces (i.e. javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD: server, javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING:true), but the error still occurs when PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING is set to false.

If any other infos are required please just ask and i will provide them.